# Discord.js can't change channel name more than twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot, which can update my voice channel name in every 5 seconds. I want to update my Minecraft players counter.

I wrote this code: (my counter here is a random number for the sake of simplicity):

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        client.channels.fetch("730344404480557076")
        .then(channel => {
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            channel.setName(`Players count: ${rand}`);
        });
    }, 5000);   
});
```

My channel's name has changed only twice. Then I can't do anything so I must create new channel with new ID.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

This is because of API Rate Limits. You can't bypass it and if you continue sending that many requests you can/will be temporarily API Banned, as with all rate limits.

The limit is 2 updates per 10 minutes.

Source: [Mason @ Discord Developers](https://discordapp.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/715995470048264233)

Comment: Do you have a source for this? If so it would be better to include it in your answer. This way future readers may be helped by reading the docs

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Yup, I'm new to answering questions, I added the source.

Comment: Sadly, the source you provided is not loading.